# MySqlConnector 6.9.9 for VS2008 (framework 3.5)

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2008, mysql-connector

I have just downloaded the newest version of the MySqlConnector ( https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/ ), which is currently Version 6.9.9.

The previous version 6.9.8, I could use in Visual Studio 2008 with framework 3.5.
But the download now only contains assemblies for v4.0 and v4.5.

Normally I just update the reference to mysql.data.dll in my project, but now I can only change it to the v4/4.5 versions, which obviously are not valid in combination with a V3.5 project.

Could anyone tell me where to find or how to download the v3.5 assembly for version 6.9.9? 
Or is V6.9.8 just the latest version for framework 3.5? (although I can't find this info anywhere)

BTW: if this is not the correct place to ask, please point to the correct community.

Edit after comment of @Programmer:

Contents of machine.config in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\CONFIG\

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="6.7.4.0" newVersion="6.9.9.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Data.Entity" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="6.7.4.0" newVersion="6.9.9.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="MySql.Web" publicKeyToken="c5687fc88969c44d" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="6.7.4.0" newVersion="6.9.9.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
...
<add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.9.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
```

Comment: I would try using nuget package manager in a more recent version of visual studio. Otherwise your alternative solution would be to manually dro p the .dll files in the respective GAC location. :/ Hope that helps! p.s. what is holding you back from switching to 4.5?

Comment: Drop the files in the GAC? You mean I can then reference a 4.0 dll in a 3.5 project? (about what's holding me back to switch...money ;) )

Comment: This is a good read for v3.5, requiring you to drop MySql.Data.dll for framework v2.0. This is an old feed but may lead you on the right direction... https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64707

Comment: That's odd. Machine.config (v2.0.50727) contains several references to 6.9.9 :| I edited my post with the contents of this machine.config.

Comment: Strange thing is, when adding a reference by browsing the .NET tab, it only lists v4.0 and v4.5 references

Comment: whats wrong with upgrading your .NET to the latest?

Comment: @krishKM I'm bound to use VS2008, which implies using framework 3.5

Comment: Try this url - http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.2.html

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation on MySQL website:

> Starting with version 6.7, Connector/Net will no longer include the
>   MySQL for Visual Studio integration. That functionality is now
>   available in a separate product called MySQL for Visual Studio
>   available using the MySQL Installer for Windows.

MySQL Installer for Windows is available for download at:

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/

Comment: Hi, thnx for your reply. Unfortunately the version of mysql.data.dll in this installation is 6.8.3  (while i have 6.9.8 already)